# ¿Cómo logro maximizar la ventana principal en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Soy nuevo programando en Phyton 3.8, y tengo una duda respecto al manejo de ventanas en Tkinter..

Cómo logro que mi ventana al ejecutar el programa, esté maximizada?

He estado buscando información en la red, pero no he tenido suerte (o no he buscado bien jejeje)... Solo con el método Geometry pero no lo veo como una solución óptima

Muchas gracias en lo que me puedan ayudar..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
root.state('zoomed')
```

☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆☆

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo !!

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], agrega más información sobre el código que propones, sería de ayuda a la comunidad, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

bueno hay otra forma sin zoomed, pero ya la respondí en otra ocasión y no se como poner ese tema aquí, con un pequeño ejemplo puedes ver a la ventana se le aplica el atributo fullscreen true o 1 para que tome el tamaño de la pantalla, también en ese ejemplo con el botón "CON OVER" desaparece las decoración del sistema operativo para esa misma ventana con la desventaja que también desaparece del manejados de ventanas y del manejados de procesos de Windows por ejemplo. es como si la aplicación fuera un fantasma que no se puede matar cerrar con el manejados de procesos,  con el botón "SIN OVER" vuelve a aparecer las decoración y vuelve a aparecer en el manejados de procesos y ventana con lo que podría cerrarse el proceso que generalmente depende de python.

```
[Como hacer fullscreen y overrideredirect entkinter almismotiempo][1]
```

puedes decirle al wm que cambié el atributo fullscreen a 1 con lo,cual la ventana pasara a tener una geometria que ocupe toda la pantalla.

[Como hacer fullscreen y overrideredirect en tkinter al mismo tiempo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/586175/287688)