# Usar zoom en ventanas con overrideredirect

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy usando Tkinter y quería hacer una ventana sin barra de titulo y que este maximizada, pero solo puedo hacer una de ellas a la vez, ya que si uso el siguiente código, la ventana ocupa toda la pantalla y no deja ver la barra de tareas.

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.state('zoomed')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede llegar a servir. Pero tiene un par de problemas.

1-No funciona si la barra de tareas del usuario se oculta automaticamente.

2-Si el usuario mueve la barra de tareas por ejemplo al lado izquierdo de la pantalla, el tamaño de la ventana no cambia.

```
from win32api import GetMonitorInfo, MonitorFromPoint

#Obtengo el area de la pantalla donde NO está la barra de tareas.
monitor_info = GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromPoint((0,0)))
work_area = monitor_info.get("Work")
work_area = work_area[2:]+work_area[:2]
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % work_area)
root.overrideredirect(True)

root.mainloop()
```

Para solucionar el segundo problema puedes hacer que el tamaño de la ventana se actualize cada tanto tiempo. Pero no lo recomiendo.

```
from win32api import GetMonitorInfo, MonitorFromPoint

import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def resize():
    #Obtengo el area de la pantalla donde NO está la barra de tareas.
    monitor_info = GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromPoint((0,0)))
    work_area = monitor_info.get("Work")
    work_area = work_area[2:]+work_area[:2]

    root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % work_area)
    root.after(10, resize)

root.overrideredirect(True)
resize()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

en TCL si existe el -zoomed, pero la verdad casi nadie lo usa, lo que usamos es el atributo -fullscreen de la ventana que permite se maximize la ventana al maximo tamaño que tenga el entorno grafico??

```
root.attributes('-fullscreen',1)
```

puedes cambiar el valor de 0 a 1 si lo quieres o no activo.

No me quedo muy bien claro, entonces hice un pequeño y simple codigo para probar que los dos modos puedan ir juntos.

cambiar los attributos overrideredirect y fullscreen, y pude comprobar, que:

cuando esta fullscreen, A primera vista no se puede notar que esten las decoraciones de ventana loos iconos que pone el manejador de ventana, porque la ventana esta en pantalla completa, con en fullscreen pero al activar el overrideredirect, la aplicacion de python desaparece del listado de ventanas de windows, lo cual implica que la aplicacion de python pasa a ser un fantasma que no se puede detectar sin un toolkit especial como twapi, que rastree las ventanas tk en el servidor X11 que genera Tkinter, donde vuelve si aparecer la ventana tk, y eso implica que si funcionan los dos modos al tiempo y con el siguiente codigo se puede probar facilmente.

```
import tkinter as tk
w=tk.Tk()
w.title('FULL Y OVER')
w.geometry('400x300+0+0')
w.attributes('-fullscreen',0)

def desover():
    w.overrideredirect(0)
def over():
    w.overrideredirect(1)
def deszoom():
    w.attributes('-fullscreen',0)
def zoom():
    w.attributes('-fullscreen',1)

b0=tk.Button(w,text="SIN OVER",command=(desover)).pack()
b0=tk.Button(w,text="CON OVER",command=(over)).pack()
b0=tk.Button(w,text="SIN FULL",command=(deszoom)).pack()
b0=tk.Button(w,text="CON FULL",command=(zoom)).pack()
b1=tk.Button(w,text="EXIT",command=(exit)).pack()

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/378589)